# Unable to get window.print() to work in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11, printing-web-page

I have 5 very simple html pages (an image and a bit of text) that I just want to be able to print what is on the page and do not care about page breaks, etc. At the close of the page, I just have a simple link: a href="#" onclick="myFunction(); return false;" with "Print This Article" as the visible text.

This works fine in Google but in IE it shows the printer dialogue screen but nothing happens after I click OK to print. I have to work in IE8 for the time being and I have all the shivs/hacks/modernizr/other js in my pages so they display correctly. I use Foundation for my pages (hence the first function below). I've read all the articles here and the ones I could understand di not seem to address whether something this simple can be made to work if no special printing is needed. Down in the function area I have these two scripts that run:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script> 

<script>
function myFunction() {
window.print();
}
</script>
```

My question is am I being oversimplistic in trying to get this simple function to work and should I be researching some of the more complex answers to things like popping up a new page, using a media calls, css, etc. Sure hope this can work though.

Thank you for any guidance/help.

Comment: if the print dialog is appearing then you're doing it right. if nothing is happening after you click "ok" in that print diaglog then that's a problem with your OS/printer set up.

Comment: I initially thought that was the case but I can get partial pages to print by just using the browser print (it only prints first page, of course). I would think if it were the printer it would choke on any printing from that page. But I will definitely dig deeper into that and report back if it helps. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Rechecked all the printer settings and not finding anything that would be a problem. Anything else I choose to print from the browser, including just printing these pages using the browser print (although it will not print more than the first visible screen), works just fine. PDF and all other printing works. And it works just fine in Google - it is just IE that will not work.

Comment: This may be the resolution but doing more testing. This is a shared network printer that I've been testing. I noticed that both Google and Firefox were inputting the full path to that printer when they opened the print dialogue. I removed the printer then reinstalled and listed the full path and then it worked. Not exactly sure why that matters - but it is the only thing I could find that was different between the three browsers. I will test again tomorrow and if it continues to print for me then will post and give jdu BIG thumbs up for sending me down this road.

Comment: This is resolved! I tested again today and it is indeed that our printer path needed to be changed in order for this to work.